# Using team foundation 2013- How to build (angular2/typescript) w/out checking in node_modules?

Tags: angular, tfs, npm

I have an angular2 application working fine locally but unable to build on build server. I do not want to check in the 29,000 files within the node_modules directory (we do a local build, test build and production build).

I have tried installing all items globally in the package.json file on the build server as the TFS Background Job Agent owner. I still get "cannot find module" errors.

I have Gulp building into a compiled single JS file, am I supposed to disable typescript compiling and just check in that JS file (would suck to not have local compilation on save and have to change to gulp compiling and file listeners). The painful part of just checking in the JS file, gulp doesn't check out the file so even though it gets updated VS doesn't know it was changed and its a pain to checkout and back in and make some small change VS detects to actually check in and migrate to the next build.

I know TFS 2015 has a new build agent, does that resolve this issue in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to post what I ended up doing in case it helps others. I did not want to check in all the node modules and I didn't want to download or manage the build server. So, I used gulp to bundle everything currently into two js files (library and app). Using gulp-tfs-commander, I could then make sure when ever gulp ran, the resulting JS files would checkout so my next check-in would just include those JS files without my involvement.

Gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var concat = require('gulp-concat')
var gulpTfs = require('gulp-tfs-commander');
var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');


gulp.task('bundle', function () {



    var builder = new Builder('/app/', 'systemjs.config.js');

    return builder
        .buildStatic('/app/main.js', 'scripts/bundled/app-bundle.js', { minify: false, mangle: false, sourceMaps: true })

        .then(function () {
            gulp.src([
                 'Scripts/bundled/app-bundle.js'
            ])
            .pipe(gulpTfs({ command: 'edit', params: { lock: 'none' } }))
            console.log('Build complete');
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Build error');
            console.log(err);
        });
});




gulp.task('bundle_library', function () {
    gulp.src([
     'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
    'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
    'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.min.js'
    ])
      .pipe(concat('nm-library.js'))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('Scripts/bundled/'))
     .pipe(gulpTfs({ command: 'edit', params: { lock: 'none' } }))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For TFS2013, you can either the corresponding command in PRE-BUILD EVENTS or extending the .crproj with custom targets. Manually edit your .csproj file at the bottom and add content as below

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CompileDependsOn>
    $(CompileDependsOn);
    GulpBuild;
  </CompileDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="GulpBuild" DependsOnTargets="CompileTypeScript">
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
  <Exec Command="gulp" />
</Target>
```

More details please refer this blog: [INTEGRATING GULP INTO YOUR TFS BUILDS AND WEB DEPLOY](http://www.codecadwallader.com/2015/03/15/integrating-gulp-into-your-tfs-builds-and-web-deploy/)

Moreover, for *TFS 2015*(vNext build system), you just need to add a [npm task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/npm-install) to run "npm install" command in your build definition to install the npm packages before VS Build.

Note: Remember to set the "Working Directory" to the project folder where the npm configuration file "package.json" is placed.

Comment: Does that means every test and production build i'm downloading the same packages again? Can they be installed globally to avoid that step, just knowing i have to update the build server if I change versions of node packages.

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you mean you want to use the packages just like GAC, can't achieve it now. And you have to update the build server if change versions of node packages to make sure the environment  on build server as same as your local.